# Spring Boot 2: Serving Mp4 videos with support for Range

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to stream Mp4 videos on my website, and support Range so you can easily navigate large videos without having to download the entire thing. Sadly for whatever reason sometimes the entire video up to the point you select is downloaded. It's like Range works half of the time

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/videos/{fileName}", produces = "video/mp4")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> streamFile(
        @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws MalformedURLException {

    String clipid = fileName.split("\\.")[0];

    final Video video = videoService.getVideo(clipid.trim());

    if (video == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new FileSystemResource(video.getFile()));
}
```

**The responses from the server:**

First position move, GOOD:

Request: `range: bytes=218202112-`

Response: `Content-Range: bytes 218202112-596696593/596696594`

Second attempt to move the time position, Full download:

Request: `range: bytes=365658112-`

Response: No content Range, only length

Answer (score 0):

So strangely enough, the issue was brought on by Cloudflare's cache system.

To fix it I simply created a page-rule to bypass caching on my video endpoints.